# What are some suggested methods to cut kerfs in long deck boards?

Tags: kerf

I am building a deck in the Pacific North West and it rains a lot so I'm using tigerwood. However, I still have cupping concerns so I am going to cut a minimum of [2] kerfs lengthwise in the 5/4 x 6 boards I have. The boards vary in length from 10-20 feet.

What are recommended ways to do this quickly and efficiently?

I have table saw (with dado blade set), skill saw, router, angle grinder, and can get others if needed.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Woodworking. We need to know what tools you have available to give proper Answers here — no point in someone saying "Just use your table saw." if you don't have a table saw. BTW just to cut to the chase here, I think the TS and (careful) use of a circular saw are the main two options. Only other alternative I can think of would be a router, but given the material and the amount you need to do I wouldn't be confident you'll get through the job without breaking at least one bit.

Comment: You could use a hand saw if you don't mind taking all month...

Comment: Cutting 100+ 10-20' long kerfs is a job that would make me buy a table saw if I didn't already have one...

Comment: Worth mentioning: decking can be purchased already machine thusly.

Comment: Yes, purchased my material and then researched how to prevent cupping... But yes I have all tools you would expect, table saw, router, skill saw, etc. Hand saw is for purists I'm sure... Thank you for your replies, much appreciated!

Comment: @njohnson what is "PNW"? Pacific North-West?

Comment: Asking for "best" will likely get closed as opinion based, as I'm sure _someone_ thinks using an angle grinder would be "best", so I changed it to "recommended options".

Answer (score 2):

You don't say what tools you have at your disposal, but this is a job for a table saw or a circular saw with a guide.

With a circular saw, you'll be running through your lumber twice, once from each end, to get your two kerfs.

With a table saw, you either run the material twice, once from either end along a fence. Or, depending on your saw and width of material, stack up two (or more) blades and spacers in a dado configuration with only the blades cutting.

A friend helping with the table saw out-feed would be recommended so you keep the rest of your fingers.

In either case, use a relatively stout rip blade intended for rough construction.

Comment: Have table saw, skill saw, router, dado blade set for table saw, angle grinder, etc. Sorry for not including.  Thanks for your suggestion!  Holy cow, the dado with just the blades on the ends is genius! Exactly what I was looking for thank you!

Comment: @njohnson please edit that list of tool options into your original question. Others may come up with good suggestions based on that, but not read this comment way down here.